# I am trying to delete the data from postgres using spark but unable to delete same code is working for select statements

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
val conn = Url
val del = s"(delete from db.table where timestamp = '1950-09-08 00:00:00.000')"
val db = DriverManager.getConnection(conn)
println("delete query :" + del)
val pstdel = db.prepareStatement(del)
try {
  pstdel.execute()  
}
```

I am getting the below error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "delete"

The same code is working for select statements. I do have delete permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val del = s"delete from db.table where timestamp = '1950-09-08 00:00:00.000'"
```